# Android TalkBack equivalent of UIKit's UIAccessibilityTraits adjustable

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Is there one? This seems so useful for vision impaired users. When a UIView has the [adjustable UIAccessibilityTrait](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/uiaccessibilitytraits/1620177-adjustable), the entire view can be focused as one unit, and the user can increase/decrease the amount of that unit or continue to swipe to other focusable elements on the screen.

As an example, imagine a screen containing a list of toppings to add to ice cream. Each topping has a plus (+) and minus button (-). With the adjustable trait, the user can swipe through the toppings, and then stop and swipe up/down to add/remove the one they want. Without the adjustable trait, each topping needs up to 3 elements on the screen that each take focus: Sprinkles (label), add button, remove button. Swiping through all these elements sounds like a nightmare for a vision impaired user.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little bit late, but that is how i implemented it in Xamarin.
I used a Frame with Buttons as root element of my component and created a new FrameRenderer.

```
using static Android.Views.Accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;
using Action = Android.Views.Accessibility.Action;

...

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomStepper), typeof(CustomStepperRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Core.Android.Renderers
{
    public class CustomStepperRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {

        public CustomStepperRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        public override void OnInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent e)
        {
            base.OnInitializeAccessibilityEvent(e);
            e.ContentDescription = (Element as CustomStepper)?.Value.ToString();
        }

        public override bool PerformAccessibilityAction([GeneratedEnum] global::Android.Views.Accessibility.Action action, Bundle arguments)
        {
            var stepper = Element as CustomStepper;
            switch (action)
            {
                case ScrollForward: return stepper.Increment();
                case ScrollBackward: return stepper.Decrement();
            }
            return base.PerformAccessibilityAction(action, arguments);
        }

        public override void OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(AccessibilityNodeInfo info)
        {
            base.OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(info);
            info.ClassName = "android.widget.seekbar";
            info.AddAction(AccessibilityAction.ActionScrollForward);
            info.AddAction(AccessibilityAction.ActionScrollBackward);
            info.ContentDescription = (Element as CustomStepper)?.Value.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```